# How to fix the alignment of a partition (MBR/DOS) when the conventional tools refuse to work?

Tags: linux, partition, ntfs

**NB:** some of the output below is from a Windows 10, but the question is nevertheless about how to rectify the issues preventing Linux from mounting said partition.

**Q:** How to fix the alignment of a partition when the conventional Linux tools refuse to work?

I have encountered a fascinating issue. A disk which I can access without trouble from Windows 10 (1903 and 1809) won't be recognized by Linux Mint (19.2), another Ubuntu 18.04 or PartedMagic booted from CD.

The respective packages are installed and I *can* mount NTFS partitions from other drives. However, this one is neither recognized by the automounter nor when I explicitly attempt to `mount`.

What's also odd is that tools such as Paragon Hard Disk Manager 15 (Linux-based rescue medium) and 16 (run from Windows) as well as PartedMagic (that is: gparted) fail to recognize the partition properly.

`diskpart` on Windows 10 shows me:

```
DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary            931 GB  1024 KB
```

The disk is initialized with MBR/DOS partition table because I thought I'd want the best compatibility and it's small enough to go without GPT.

The offset seems slightly odd to me, but to my knowledge that would usually be an issue for Windows, rather than Linux, when trying to mount a volume (partition).

But then Paragon Hard Disk Manager 16, run from Windows 10 **reports this**:

> Paragon Hard Disk Manager™ has discovered problems with this
>   partition. It must have been caused by an incorrect geometry. In order
>   to resolve the issue, please collect LOG-files and send them to our
>   Support Team

It also reports (in conjunction with the previous message):

```
Invalid partition

HDD number: 2
Partition number: 0

                               Sector No:        | Cyl:   | Hd: | Sec:
-------------------------------------------------|--------|-----|-----
First physical sector: | 0x800 (2048)            | 0      | 32  | 33
Last physical sector:  | 0x74705FFF (1953521663) | 121601 | 25  | 24
Hard disk geometry:    |                         | 121597 | 255 | 63
```

So probably alignment or something related to it is an issue here.

```
DISKPART> detail disk

ZALMAN ZM-VE500 USB Device
Disk ID: XXXXXXXX
Type   : USB
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 1     D   XXXXXX.1TB   NTFS   Partition    931 GB  Healthy
DISKPART> select volume=1

Volume 1 is the selected volume.

DISKPART> detail volume

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
* Disk 2    Online          931 GB      0 B

Read-only              : No
Hidden                 : No
No Default Drive Letter: No
Shadow Copy            : No
Offline                : No
BitLocker Encrypted    : No
Installable            : Yes

Volume Capacity        :  931 GB
Volume Free Space      :   58 GB
```

So as I can also tell from it being mounted, Windows 10 seems quite happy with the partition the way it is.

So how can I fix the alignment to something more digestible for Linux when the Linux-based tools I've tried failed me?

It seems to be quite the catch 22 situation, since the tools I have tried so far (gdisk, gparted/parted, sfdisk/cfdisk, fdisk) fail at various stages. Some report a corrupted GPT, others don't indicate any issues but don't provide the operations required to move/resize the partition without data loss (or extraneous copying).

*Please note:* the point here is not to avoid data loss due to having no (other) backup, but rather to avoid a lengthy session of copying data which already exists in-place. And yes, I figure that probably waiting for an answer takes longer than copying to a temporary storage, fixing the partitioning and then copying the stuff back. However, I've never had Linux tools fail me like that when it came to partitioning and alignment of partitions and so I am curious about how to rectify this without having to resort to the extraneous copying.

---

Find below the output of various tools. The output of `ntfsinfo` is identical to the one when attempting to mount said partition:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 931.5 GiB, 1000172421120 bytes, 1953461760 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5c742dd9

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 1953521663 1953519616 931.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


$ sudo sfdisk -X dos /dev/sdc

Welcome to sfdisk (util-linux 2.31.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Checking that no-one is using this disk right now ... OK

Disk /dev/sdc: 931.5 GiB, 1000172421120 bytes, 1953461760 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5c742dd9

Old situation:

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 1953521663 1953519616 931.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Type 'help' to get more information.

$ sudo ntfsinfo -m /dev/sdc1
Failed to read last sector (1953519614): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc1' doesn't have a valid NTFS.
Maybe you selected the wrong device? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/hda, not /dev/hda1)? Or the other way around?
Failed to open '/dev/sdc1'.

$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdc
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by
typing 'q' if you don't want to convert your MBR partitions
to GPT format!
***************************************************************


Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdc: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Model: USB3.0          
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): DCB1968C-54AE-4EBB-9FD8-3899FAF16767
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 5485 sectors (2.7 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048      1953521663   931.5 GiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
```